# Can't seem to hover the drop-down menu via CSS

Tags: html, css

To be upfront, I just started a Web Designing module in school, hence I'm quite new to this stuff.

Here's the thing, I attempted to create a CSS drop-down menu but I'm not sure why the drop-down menu isn't appearing. Is the "display"/"visibility"/"opacity" property in "ul li ul" element causing the trouble, or it's just another thing?

```css
/* Navigation */
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 float:right;
 margin-right: 50px;
}
nav ul li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 margin-right: -5px;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
}
nav ul li a{
 color: #000000;;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px; 
 padding: 15px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #1D55D5; 
}
ul li ul {
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
 top:48px;
 width:150px;
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
   -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
 background: #555;
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li: hover {
  background: #666;
}
ul li: hover ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul><li><a href="updates.html">Updates!</a></li>
    <li><a>About Me!</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Personal Life</li>
        <li>Game Stuff</li>        
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Find me on the Web!</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

Comment: `li: hover` should be `li:hover`

Comment: It's at least partly because you have a space where you shouldn't: `ul li: hover ul {` should be `ul li:hover ul {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's related to the `display/visibility/opacity` property in the `ul li ul` element.

Currently, your `ul li ul` is hidden. What you want is to make sure the inner ul it's **not hidden** when you hover the `ul li` element

```
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Check this example (also fixed some css problems in the original code. check the `li :hover` for example):

```css
/* Navigation */
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 float:right;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

nav ul li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 margin-right: -5px;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 
 
}

nav ul li a{
 color: #000000;;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px; 
 padding: 15px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #1D55D5; 
}

ul li ul {
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
 top:48px;
 width:150px;
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
   -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
ul li ul li {
 background: #555;
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

ul li ul li:hover { background: #666;
}

ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul><li><a href="updates.html">Updates!</a></li>
      <li><a>About Me!</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Personal Life</li>
          <li>Game Stuff</li>        
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Find me on the Web!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: yeah, did an overall fix for the code :) added also the `<header>` element to the code (since it exists in the css)

Comment: ah so that's the problem.. thanks a lot mate, appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove redundant properties `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0`; from  `ul li ul {}` selector, because on `ul li:hover ul` you change only `display` property to `block`. This way you won't have transitions. But it should work. Hope this helps. Good luck!